# Save to csv a pivot table get error "Process finished with exit code 139"

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a question about pandas.
I'm new to pandas and I can't understand what's causing this error. I searched the Internet and stackoverflow for answers but couldn't find anything about it.

```
from pandas import read_csv, pivot_table
f_csv = read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=file_dir, delimiter=';')
res_pivot = pivot_table(f_csv, index=['nome_ua'], columns=['attivita_descrizione'], values=['produzione_data_inizio', 'produzione_data_fine'], aggfunc=lambda x: x)
res_pivot.to_csv('/tmp/result.csv', sep=';', quotechar='"')
```

The CSV file has 344 rows and 7 columns.
I'm using TurboGears 2.3.5, and upon calling `.to_csv` the main process terminates with this message: `Process finished with exit code 0`.

This was very strange, so I did the same with ipython and instead got this message: `Process finished with exit code 139`. 139 seems to mean "invalid memory access"  (SIGSEGV).

After looking for solutions to similar errors I changed the last line to:

```
res_pivot.to_csv('/tmp/result.csv', sep=';', quotechar='"', chunksize=10)
```

But the outcome is still the same.

Contents of res_pivot.head(): http://pastebin.com/YKcrkCjf (it's really large)

Contents of res_pivot.columns:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'produzione_data_inizio', u'produzione_data_fine'], [u'Bovini - Allevamento  autoconsumo', u'Bovini - Da riproduzione', u'Bovini - Ingrasso', u'Bovini - Linea vacca vitello', u'Bovini - Produzione latte']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
       names=[None, u'attivita_descrizione'])
```

Last rows http://pastebin.com/N7gX22AQ
Used res_pivot.tail() and res_pivot.values[0:][250:]

I tried leaving only 5 rows in the CSV, and everything worked just fine.

Could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Please post the head of your "res_pivot" data frame.

Comment: If you look at the data, is there something odd at the rows 344 or 345? Maybe show those rows?

Comment: @joris I see that in pivot mode has 272 row. Added to the question, thanks

Comment: Would ik be possible/allowed to post the full contents of the data you try to write? And what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Ok. i'm really confused. http://pastebin.com/WCjziD9X. I make some test with a `.values` and this is result. here link of csv https://www.dropbox.com/s/tcse21izqs7slxq/2015-07-1435919885-12-38-05-806282.csv?dl=0. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems lies in this: `aggfunc=lambda x: x`.
This is *not* an aggregating function, but just returns the values as it gets them. The `aggfunc` argument is supposed to get a function that is used to aggregate for cases where the given `index` and `columns` combination in `pivot_table` gives multiple values. Because you do not aggregate them, you end up with a dataframe containing arrays as elements. And apparently, `to_csv` chokes on that.

To solve the issue, you need to provide an function that aggregates (the default is taking the mean). Since you don't have numeric values, a possibility is taking the first value (`aggfunc='first'` will work for this, as 'first' is a recognized shortcut for a function that takes the first value). Using this it works without crashing:

```
In [10]: res_pivot = pd.pivot_table(f_csv, index=['nome_ua'], 
                                    columns=['attivita_descrizione'],
                                    values=['produzione_data_inizio', 'produzione_data_fine'],
                                    aggfunc='first')

In [11]: res_pivot.to_csv('tmp_result.csv', sep=';', quotechar='"')
```

Comment: good works perfectly, and if i want write 'produzione_data_inizio' and 'produzione_data_fine' in same cell? and not duplicate head?. anyway thanks

Comment: What do you mean with 'in the same cell'?

Comment: I mean I'd like to concatenate 'produzione_data_inizio' and 'produzione_data_fine' inside the same cell, rather than having a copy of every column in _columns_ . How would I accomplish that?